# Custom sort in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I need to sort objects that look like this:

```
{id: x, startDate:"mm/yyyy", endDate:"mm/yyyy", title:"xxxx", ...}
{id: y, startDate:"mm/yyyy", endDate:"", title:"xxxx", ...}
```

I want the objects to be sorted using `endDate` (most recent ended first). The end date can also be blank, in which case the object is still active and needs to be at the top. In the case of equal end dates, they should be sorted by start date, most recent first.

I can't do simple string comparing as 10/2013 is more recent than 02/2010. So the comparison should work both on start and end date, and year (`date.substring(3,7)`) and month (`date.substring(0,2)`).

**EDIT**

I have the following in my view:

```
ng-repeat="project in ProfileController.person.projects|orderBy:dateSorter"
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.dateSorter = function(project) {
    return project.endDate.length ? -"9999" : -project.endDate.substring(3,7);
};
```

which correctly sort the projects by descending end **year**. Now I need to take months into account, as well as start dates in the case of equal end dates.

Comment: What is causing you problems?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXEzU8s8huS0HGFPDEnI?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('startDate', reverse); reverse=!reverse">Start Date</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('endDate',reverse);reverse=!reverse">End Date</a></th>
      <th>Title</th>  
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items"> 
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.startDate | date:'MM-yyyy'}}</td> 
      <td>{{item.endDate }}</td>
      <td>{{item.title }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope,$filter){      
   var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');         
   $scope.items = [
                  {id: 1, startDate:"02/2010", endDate:"02/2010", title:"Title1"},
                  {id: 2, startDate:"01/2010", endDate:"01/2010", title:"Title2"};
                 ];                  
   $scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
       $scope.items = orderBy($scope.items, predicate, reverse);
   };

});
```

Comment: This is not what my problem is about. I need to be able to (1) handle empty end date strings (2) take into account these are dates, so you can't do simple string comparing

Comment: I will be helpful for us to answer your question if you add plunker/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an comparison function to Array.prototype.sort(). You should provide it with a function that implements your ordering specifications as follows :

```
function mmYyyyToDate(mmYyyy) {
    return new Date(mmYyyy.substring(3,7), mmYyyy.substring(0, 2))
}

function compares(a, b) {
    if (a.endDate && b.endDate) {
        var aEndDate = mmYyyyToDate(a.endDate);
        var bEndDate = mmYyyyToDate(b.endDate);
        return aEndDate == bEndDate ? 0 : aEndDate < bEndDate ? -1 : 1
    } else if (a.endDate) { return -1; }
    } else if (b.endDate { return 1; }
    } else {
        var aStartDate = mmYyyyToDate(a.startDate);
        var bStartDate = mmYyyyToDate(b.startDate);
        return aStartDate == bStartDate ? 0 : aStartDate < bStartDate ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

You could implement that in a filter if you need to sort the array for display, or just call it in your controller or providing service if you want your data sorted at all time.

Comment: I know, but the problem is I don't know how to implement this function